# How can I list and import files into from a subdirectory?

Tags: r, import

I know how to list and import files from the main directory in R using list.files. But how can I do it for a deeper directory?

Example:

```
-a1
   - 2001
      - files
      - files
   - 2002
      - files
      - files
```

Here a1 is the main directory and I want to import files under directories 2001, 2002 etc. It would be nice if I could

- list all subdirectories
- Read and import files from each subdirectory present

I tried doing this:

```
templist <- list.files(pattern = ".precip/2010/*.tif")
```

Answer (score 1):

You can list all subdirectories with:

```
tempdirlist=list.dirs("path\\to\\dir\\a1")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can browse subdirectories by setting `recursive = T`. Set `full.names=F` to append the name of the subdirectory (folder) to each filename instead of the path.

```
setwd("~/Desktop/Data")
files <- list.files(recursive = T, full.names = F,pattern = ".precip/2010/*.tif")
df <- list()
for (i in files) {tempData <- scan(i)
df[[i]] <- tempData}
df <- as.data.frame(df)
```

This gives you one big data frame containing all files in the different subdirectories as columns. Each column name starts with the name of the subdirectory. Finally you can use the columnnames to separate the big dataframe into one for each subdirirectory for example.

```
samples <- (unique(substr(files,1,4))) #in this example the first 4 signs are the same for every file in a subdirectory so I can use this string to seperate the big dataframe
for (i in samples) {
tempData <- df %>% select(starts_with(i))
names <- colnames(tempData)
assign(substr(names[1],1,nchar(names[1])-13),tempData) #if you wand to create a data.frame for each sample
}
```